# Order MySQL Table by Ascending Order (Numbers)

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to arrange est_dilt_pple table in ascending order.

```
   pub_name                               est_dily_pple
    Jex Max Publication                         11530
    BPP Publication Mumbai                  123500    
    New Harrold Publication                     12563
    Ultra Press Inc.                            9500
    Mountain Publication                        9300
    Summer Night Publication                    53698
    Pieterson Grp. of Publishers                50000
```

**i tried this**

```
SELECT * FROM publisher ORDER BY est_dily_pple ASC;
```

**Result**

```
pub_name                               est_dily_pple
Jex Max Publication                         11530
BPP Publication Mumbai                  123500
New Harrold Publication                     12563
Pieterson Grp. of Publishers                50000    
Summer Night Publication                    53698
Mountain Publication                        9300
Ultra Press Inc.                            9500
```

**PROBLEM**

But it is not ascending. "123500" is more than all, it should showed at bottom. any help me in this please!

Comment: What is the datatype for that column ?

Comment: I don't think that est_dily_pple has Integer type.

Comment: I am sure est_dily_pple is char or varchar as it is getting sorted in terms of string

change its type to int

Comment: @TheNewIdiot its integer

Comment: @user2336315 yes its in integer only

Comment: can you please post your code which you used to create tabel
something line create table publisher (pub_name varchar(30), est_dily_pple int)

Comment: use this query
desc publisher;
and post result here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to make the datatype of column `est_dily_pple` numeric. Or else you can try this :

```
SELECT * FROM publisher ORDER BY CAST(est_dily_pple as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

Comment: Yes it would work, but I think that the error there is that the schema of the database is clearly wrong !

Comment: This will work, but it'll mean a TABLE SCAN for every SELECT.  You'll have to do it every row.

Comment: I mentioned this as a *secondary* solution .

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the column is a text or varchar type, with string sorting semantics.

Make it an integer or number type and you'll fare better.

Comment: @user2457175 Really ? Show us that.

Comment: I think not....if it were, the sorting would be correct AND you wouldn't have that odd rendering for the one value that's a problem.   Show the DDL for the table.